# Remove item from async storage not working

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have below code in signout screen

```
 await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken').then(()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
      }, 3000);
```

On splash screen I am checking like this

```
const userToken = AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken').then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'SignIn');
    });
```

After signout Its redirect to sign-in, but when I open the app again splash screen moves to app rather than sign-in

My inital code was like

```
const userToken = AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'), this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'SignIn');
```

What I am doing wrong.
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: as long as you're using `await` ... there's no need for `then`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to execute it anyway

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the Async data result?

eg:

> On splash screen

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken").then(value => {
      if(value) {
       let token = JSON.parse(value);
       this.props.navigation.navigate(token ? 'App' : 'SignIn');
      } else {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
      }
    });
```

Comment: I dont need the data result

Comment: Ok, but you can check whether it is appear or not. Based on this status you can navigate.

Comment: let it be undefined

Answer (score 1):

You forget the param of callback,

```
const userToken = AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken').then((userToken) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'SignIn');
    });
```

Comment: is it really required, If I don't have to do anything with userToken

Comment: so how you gonna check ? returned value is undefined or it has string in it ?

Comment: My actual code was like const userToken = AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken'),  this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'SignIn');

Comment: So its is undefined so it should redirect to signin

Comment: yes now you came to right point, make it await and it will work.

Comment: I tried this, but it was not working, thats y I m trying this

Comment: have you tried logging  userToken's value ? what it gives ?

Comment: It always gives object

Comment: well, we can set only string values in async storage... so you need to log `JSON.stringify(userToken)` with await and see what it prints

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented the same functionality like this

```
async logout() {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    Actions.SignIn(); // for navigating back to sign in screen if using router flux
    this.props.navigation.navigate("SignIn"); // if using react-navigation
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file `AndroidManifest.xml` and change `android:allwoBackup=ture` to `android:allwoBackup=false`. Hope this will work. When backup is true it always backup login information.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still confused or finding the solution here

Then here is the solution :

```
const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken').then(() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'SignIn');
});
```

Just add `await` when you are getting a value of a key from AsyncStorage

I also had this problem BTW.